# Cutting rectangles in runtime with shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have a problem and no experience with writing shaders in Unity itself. So far the default shaders have been enough for me. But now I need a shader (standard render pipeline) that makes everything transparent except certain rectangles of my texture. I need to be able to change these rectangles while the game is running. There are 24 different ones, and I only need a few of each. I've already tried using alpha clipping, but I'm not really getting anywhere. How can I do this? Is that even possible? How do I access the shader in my C# code?

I tried alpha clipping, but I don't know how to set the vectors for clipping.